# Exceeded part could not respond to click event about android:clipChildren attribute?

Tags: android, android-layout

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:background="#B0C4DE"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:drawableTop="@mipmap/zxj64"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:text="act"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

code:

```
        val tv = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv)
        tv.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this,"hello！",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

[image: figure1]

I want to use `android:clipChildren` attribute to achieve the effect beyond the parent view ,but it can't respond to click events,I have no way,I can't start.
I searched for a day,There is no answer in the whole network. help me please.

I uploaded all the code and it prompted me to code too much, I can only delete some and become weird. It is actually a bottom navigation bar

Comment: Do your clicks register if you click on different parts of your text view? Your layout structure looks strange, so parts of your view may be obscured, or other views are consuming interactions first.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There should be a minimum content in one question: Input sample (if needed), expected output sample (is needed), what you try, what you research... What did you try? What did you find and why it is not fixing your problem?